# jekyll: getting error when trying to output array of products from _data/products.yml

Tags: html, yaml, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to build a product list from `products.yml` located in the _data directory with a `for loop` in **jekyll** so that the end result would look like this: [**example**](https://dev.eshkolet.co.il/order/) built with handlebars.js

First I wrote a YAML file in `_data/products.yml` with a list of products divided into categories

```
---
categories:
- Baking Products:
  - name: Vegetable oil
  - name: Vinegar
  - ...
- Dairy Products:
  - name: Cream Cheese
  - name: Cottage Cheese
  - ...
- Other Products:
  - name: Peanut butter
  - name: Chocolate spread
  - ...
```

Now I want to iterate over all categories, and for evry cateory to iterate over all its products and displaying some info about them:

```
{% for category in site.data.products %}
  <div class="plist">
    <div class="category">
      <h3>{{ category.name }</h3>
      <span>Qty</span>
    </div>
    {% for product category.products %}
      <div class="product checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ product.name | capitalize }}" value="{{ product.name }}">
        <label  for="{{ product.name | capitalize }}">{{name}}</label>
        <select name="{{ product.name }}" id="{{ product.name | capitalize }}Q" autocomplete="off" class="dropdown">
          <option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% if loop.index0 % 2 == 0 %}
    <break></break>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

getting this error:

> Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 13): Variable '{{ category.name }' was not properly terminated with regexp: /}}/ in order.html
>
> jekyll 3.8.5 | Error:  Liquid syntax error (line 13): Variable '{{ category.name }' was not properly terminated with regexp: /}}/

Comment: See this line: `<h3>{{ category.name }</h3>`

Comment: @ashmaroli see what? I don't understand please explain..

Comment: spent hours trying to figure it out..
couldn't find answer on the internet

Comment: Liquid variables need to be enclosed inside a pair of double-braces:  `{{ category.name }}`

Comment: @ashmaroli ok I fixed that enclosed double-braces and it still gives me an error
 `Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 16): Syntax Error in 'for loop' - Valid syntax: for [item] in [collection] in order.html
jekyll 3.8.5 | Error:  Liquid syntax error (line 16): Syntax Error in 'for loop' - Valid syntax: for [item] in [collection]`

Comment: @ashmaroli thank u for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is the fixed code.

Thanks @ashmaroli

```
{% for category in site.data.products %}
  <div class="plist">
    <div class="category">
      <h3>{{ category.name }}</h3>    <!-- missing "}" -->
      <span>Qty</span>
    </div>
    {% for product in category.products %}   <!-- missing "in" -->
      <div class="product checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" id="{{ product.name | capitalize }}" value="{{ product.name }}">
        <label  for="{{ product.name | capitalize }}">{{name}}</label>
        <select name="{{ product.name }}" id="{{ product.name | capitalize }}Q" autocomplete="off" class="dropdown">
          <option value="0">0</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
  {% cycle '','<break></break>' %}   <!-- fixed -->
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The parameter here should be `forloop`: `{% if forloop.index0 % 2 == 0 %}`

Comment: I used this `{% cycle '','<break></break>' %}` and it worked great! thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Liquid Variable needs to be enclosed within double braces:

```
{{ category.name }}
```

and Liquid tags need to be a pair of *brace-percents*:

```
{% seo %}
```